# What does "Income generated in the U.S." mean?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, corporation

Quoting from [Stripe.com - Incorporation - Why should I incorporate in Delaware?](https://stripe.com/atlas/faq#incorporation):

> [...] Pay federal income tax on income generated in the U.S.

Does that mean I cannot do any business with any American company? Does that mean I cannot accept any money from any American company?

Comment: If you are trying to open a bank account and run your business with US-based companies, then you will have to pay income tax on any money received (modulo any applicable deductions).

Comment: Why not incorporate elsewhere than the U.S. if you want to avoid that? Plenty of companies around the world earn money from sales to Americans and American companies without having to pay American income tax.

Answer (score 1):

It means you must pay federal (and possibly state) tax on any income you produce in America -- including Internet and mail-order sales. Tax treaties may keep you from having to pay tax on it again in your own country, or may not.